# How to write a variable with unfixed length along one dimension into a netCDF file

Tags: c++, c, netcdf, netcdf4

The structure of my data is as follows,

```
dimensions:
        int np = 25;
        int ns
        int nk = 10

variables:
        double period(np);
        double data(nk,ns,np)
```

The problem is that the `ns` dimension is not fixed. For example, the `data` can be like this:

```
data(10,300,1)
data(10,200,2)
data(10,108,3)
data(10,500,4)
...
```

How to write such dataset to a netCDF file?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a "ragged array". Unfortunately, netCDF does not intrinsically support ragged arrays. You would need to allocate variables with each dimension the maximum size needed to store all the entries possible along that dimension. If you then need to indicate the unused entries, you can rely on the `_FillValue` as a sentinel value, or need to use a secondary variable to indicate the true number of entries in a dimension for a particular combination of indices for the other dimensions.